# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType"

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my very first programming class and I'm having a hard time with this problem. I can't seem to get this to work I keep getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType"

```
def woodtype(wood):
    MAH=float(75.00)
    OAK=float(100)
    coffetab=float(0)
if woodtype=="mahogany":
    coffetab=MAH
else:
    if woodtype=="oak":
        coffetab=OAK


lamp=65
tables=155
print("the cost per desk lamp is $%.2f" %lamp)
print("the cost per coffee table is $%.2f" %tables)
dl=input("how many desk lamps are you buying?:")
desklamps=int(dl)
cf=input("how many coffee tables are you buying?:")
coffeetables=int(cf)
print("what type of wood would you like the coffee tables; mahogany, oak or pine.")
wood=input("what type of wood for your coffee tables?:")
costofwood=woodtype(wood)
total= (desklamps*65)+(coffeetables*(15+costofwood))
print("the total cost of your purchase is $%.2f" %total)
```

Comment: Your function `woodtype(wood)` doesn't return anything, so the variable is assigned `None`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a help forum. The distinction is critical: We care about quality in our questions as much as in our answers, because the questions are content too. Please try to follow the rules at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; to minimize the content of code sections to focus on a single, specific error with everything unneeded to create that error removed; and to reflect the nature of that error in your question's title (which is how other people with the same problem are expected to find that question and its answers).

Comment: You have defined `woodtype` as a function.  It will not compare equal to any string.  So comparing it to `"mahogany"` or `"oak"` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:
Firstly, Python uses whitespace to determine blocks, which drops your if/else outside of the `woodtype` function.
Secondly, if you don’t supply an *explicit* return statement for `woodtype`, then Python will supply an *implicit* `None` return value.
Lastly, the `woodtype` function takes a parameter named `wood`, but you've used `woodtype` in the if statement.

After correcting these issues the function should look something like

```
def woodtype(wood):
    MAH=float(75.00)
    OAK=float(100)
    coffetab=float(0)

    if wood=="mahogany":
        coffetab=MAH
    elif wood=="oak":
        coffetab=OAK

    return coffetab
```

Comment: Still does nothing. `wood` would be valid instead of `woodtype`

Comment: def wood:( )
    MAH=float(75.00)
    OAK=float(100)
    coffetab=float(0)

    if wood=="mahogany":
        coffetab=MAH
    elif wood=="oak":
        coffetab=OAK

    return coffeetab

Comment: ^So would I do that instead^ ?

Comment: the updated version in my answer will work, in the original the if statement was checking a non-existent variable